# Construct With Type Which Contains Nested Table

Tags: types, plsql

I have a type which contains a constructor which accepts an array. I'd like to build an array of that type and feed in the child array at the same time.

As an example

```
create type child as object
(
    name varchar2(10)
);
/
create type children as table of child;
/
create type parent as object
(
    name varchar2(10),
    my_children children
);
/
create type parents as table of parent;
/
create table child_table
(
    parent_name varchar2(10),
    child_name varchar2(10)
);
/
create table parent_table 
(
    name varchar2(10)
);
/
declare
    l_parents parents;
begin
    select parent(p.name, (select child(c.child_name) from child_table where parent_name = p.name))
    bulk collect into l_parents
    from parent_table p;
end;
```

The fourth to last line (select parent(p.name....)) is just pseudocode and is the one I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT parent(p.name,
              CAST((SELECT COLLECT (child(c.child_name))
                      FROM child_table c
                     WHERE parent_name = p.name
                   ) AS children
                  )
             )
  BULK COLLECT INTO  l_parents
  FROM parent_table p;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare
    l_parents parents;
begin
    select parent(p.name,  cast(multiset(select c.child_name from child_table c where parent_name = p.name)as children))
    bulk collect into l_parents
    from parent_table p;
end;
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.